# How to manage production of box plots if you have a massive number of data points?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Consider the following snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(1, 5760000)
plt.boxplot(data)
```

It takes a long time, and a lot of memory, for matplotlib to plot this.

What can I do better?

One idea I had is to calculate the min, max, median, first quartile, and third quartile using numpy. Then, I can give these values directly to `boxplot`, so that it doesn't have to do the calculations.

This snippet of code runs very fast:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(1, 5760000)
fq, median, tq = np.quantile(data, [0.25, 0.5, 0.75])
dmin, dmax = np.min(data), np.max(data)
```

However, there is no such option (that I can see).

The second idea I had is to manually draw the box plot given the above statistics, but that requires me to deal with the details of matplotlib artists, and I'd like to avoid that if possible.

The third idea I had is to just use a simpler style to plot the relevant box plot quantities. It won't look like a box plot, but it conveys the same information.

I am going to run with the third idea for now, but I hope there is a way for me to just use `boxplot` directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First: `boxplot` interprets `data = np.random.rand(1, 10)` differently from `data = np.random.rand(10, 1)`. The first is interpreted as a list of 10 box plots, each created from 1 data point, while the second is interpreted as a list of 1 box plot, each with 10 data points.

Therefore, passing `np.rand.rand(1, 5760000)` plots `5760000` individual box plots in a single graph. This is what is time and memory consuming. You actually want to pass `np.rand.rand(5760000, 1)`, since you want to plot one box plot with statistics from a data set containing ~6 million data points.

Second: the following page answers how to manually pass data to the box plot drawer function: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/statistics/bxp.html

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(5760000,1)
plt.boxplot(data)
```

Comment: Alright, I'm stumped. Did something massive change in `numpy` or `matplotlib` between 2019 and 2022? This answer appears to be what the author intended, whereas `plt.boxplot(np.random.rand(1,10))` just shows bars for 10 points.

Comment: Nevertheless, code-only answers are usually discouraged. Can you edit this answer to help explain the difference? Also see: [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).